# How to add spacing in the html() function in jquery?

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

### Hello Guys!

See I have been creating a code powered with **`ajax`** but it is way too long and that's why I can't show it here, Sorry for this. But I have created a sample like thing in my Problem Demo link (below). You visit that page and see the **problem** by your own **eyes**! But here is the jQuery code of my sample ---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document.body).html('
                         <div>
                             This is Complex Jquery Code Sample!
                         </div>
                         '); 
});
```

But when I enter my code in a single line (which I'm currently using in my original code) it shows everything perfect. But the problem is in my original code the HTML string is very long and so I'm unable to manage it quickly and effectively! Below is the link for the working one.

[**WORKING ONE**](http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/Sv4Bc/)

Hope you guys can help me out with this one. Or else I have to do a long coding on a single line which is very **uncomfortable**!

**[PROBLEM DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/UNnKx/)**

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Are you retrieving that HTML string via Ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your code to look like the following it should work.
Note the double quotes and the \ at the end of each line

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document.body).html("\
                         <div>\
                             This is Complex Jquery Code Sample!\
                         </div>\
                         "); 
});
```

Comment: Why double quotes for your javaScript strings? Single quotes let you embed double quotes for e.g. class names for markup strings without having to escape them.

Comment: That's true.  I guess it really depends on what I am typing out.  If it were to need double quotes I would have used single quote wrappers. It is more or less an odd habit I have I guess.

Comment: Thanks buddy this worked in first attempt! Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for multi-line strings?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document.body).html('\
                         <div>\
                             This is Complex Jquery Code Sample!\
                         </div>\
                         '); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(document.body).html(''+
                         '<div>'+
                             'This is Complex Jquery Code Sample!'+
                         '</div>'+
                         ''); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can start writing your HTML using a DOM plugin it will be something like this

```
$(document.body).html($.DIV({}, "This is Complex jQuery Code Sample"));
```

a table would be something like this:

```
var table =
   $.TABLE({ Class:"MyTable" },
      $.TBODY({},
         $.TR({ Class:"MyTableRow" },
            $.TD({ Class:"MyTableCol1" }, 'howdy' ),
            $.TD({ Class:"MyTableCol2" },
               'Link: ',
               $.A({ Class:"MyLink", href:"http://www.example.com" },
                  'example.com'
               )
            )
         )
      )
   );
```

http://mg.to/2006/02/27/easy-dom-creation-for-jquery-and-prototype

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an excellent use case for jQuery templates.

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/16/microsoft-jquery-and-templating.aspx

Is that an option. It would be much easier to maintain a jquery template than it would be to edit large amounts of markup in js syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to hard-code long strings of HTML code into your JavaScript code. Instead, keep the HTML code inside a .html file, and then retrieve it via Ajax:

code.html:

```
<div>
    This is Complex Jquery Code Sample!
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.get('code.html', function(data) {
    $('body').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but my `Ajax` script retrieves some information for a `php` file and displays it. That's why I will not be able to include any original HTML code. But Thanks anyway, because you let me know a great jQuery function!